# How to convert string with abbreviated month name to Date using as.Date()?

Tags: r, dataframe, date, dplyr, data-cleaning

I have a column that contains date and time separated by " " which I was able to split into 2 columns called "dates" and "time". Now I want to select the non empty rows from the date column and convert that column to date type (right now its in char type. I checked using `typeof()`). I used

```
mutate(DATE=as.Date(dates, format="%m/%d/%y"))
```

but the new DATE column is just `<NA>` as shown in the image.

Here is the screenshot of my program and the outcome for your kind reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOMnb.png)

this is the outcome:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdOn2.png)

I tried to change the date format to `"%Y-%m-%d"` also but no use.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `%b` format string for abbreviated month names like so:

```
> x
[1] "30-MAY-2024" "05-SEP-2024" "28-DEC-2023" "14-DEC-2023" "11-JUL-2024"
> as.Date(x, '%d-%b-%Y')
[1] "2024-05-30" "2024-09-05" "2023-12-28" "2023-12-14" "2024-07-11"
```

Not sure why you had split the date and time, you also could have used `strptime`.

```
> y
[1] "15-DEC-2023 19:12:27" "29-DEC-2023 09:12:27" "27-JUL-2024 00:12:27" "07-DEC-2024 07:12:27"
[5] "03-MAR-2024 12:12:27"
> strptime(y, '%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S')
[1] "2023-12-15 19:12:27 CET"  "2023-12-29 09:12:27 CET"  "2024-07-27 00:12:27 CEST"
[4] "2024-12-07 07:12:27 CET"  "2024-03-03 12:12:27 CET"
```

See `?strftime` for more format strings.

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(x)
c("30-MAY-2024", "05-SEP-2024", "28-DEC-2023", "14-DEC-2023", 
"11-JUL-2024")

> dput(y)
c("15-DEC-2023 19:12:27", "29-DEC-2023 09:12:27", "27-JUL-2024 00:12:27", 
"07-DEC-2024 07:12:27", "03-MAR-2024 12:12:27")
```